# unable to save the exact date in database

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I have tried many times to store the exact date which I have selected. But when saving, it will take the previous date. I have tested in many ways, the angular file will pass the same selected date. When the sql query is executed, then it will take the incorrect date. can anyone please help me to solve this?

Below is my code.
html code:

```
     <td class="data_field">
         <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date_main_domain" ng-model="domain.date_main_domain" id="date_main_domain" required value="{{domain.date_main_domain}}">
     </td>
```

sql query:

```
    $database->execute( "UPDATE domain_information SET date_main_domain='$dateMainDomain' WHERE id=$domainId" );
```

Comment: what is your $dateMainDomain value ?

Comment: sorry, here is the value it will take when saving, Fri Mar 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: Could it be that your database server time isn't set as you would like it ? Just a guess.

Comment: can u include the error? or maybe it might help if you check where the error occurs, try checking in your client-side if its a valid date object and for database check for data type in your column

Comment: I am actually not receiving any error when saving or fetching the date from table. but it will take the incorrect date. The column type is  datetime

Comment: is there any ways to change the date format similar to database server date format? how can I get to know what is server's date format? @arnold emzi

Comment: yes there is, i recommend you use it its easy to use

Comment: Thank you so much @arnold emzi, the code you have added early was useful and it worked for me!! could you please add it again ? so that others can refer it when they get error.

Comment: sure no problem glad it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a valid date for the database to accept it, format your date object

```
        function formatDate(date) {
            var d = new Date(date),
                month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                day = '' + d.getDate(),
                year = d.getFullYear();

            if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

            return [year, month, day].join('-');
        }

        // date object to save
        var date = new Date(formatDate($scope.domain.date_main_domain));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a timezone issue to me.

I guess on angular side the local timezone of the browser is taken.

Then you send it to the server. From my experience i would say it's beeing transfered as a utc time which represents the same time as the local time in the browser. So, for instance if the user is located in china at 12:00 (UTC+8), i guess 04:00 UTC-0 will be transfered.

At the server side the date will be set. Dependent on the methods you call on the date object you will see the utc-0 or the server timezone based representation.

You should analysis the date inside your request which goes to the server. If you just want the right day and don't care about the local timezone of the user you might concider to change the timezone  of your date to Utc-0 on frontend side before you send it. (use a copy, so that you don't affect ypur model date)